# Visual Basic .NET how to finishing application without closing form

Tags: vb.net

I am studying Visual Basic .NET

I would like to know that finishing application on the form without closing form.

For example, I am running task(without using thread) on the form.

When I click "stop" button, i would like to finish (like go to the end of program) without closing form.

I tried disposing or application.close. It was stopping and go to the end of the code. However, it was closing the form.

is there anyway that just finish task and keeping the form ?

Comment: If you are not using a thread, does that mean that you are on the UI thread? If so, you cannot respond to user events. You need to use another thread for this.

Comment: Like Paul said, unless you are using another thread, then your running task will be blocking the UI thread and the user will never be able to press the stop button at all.

Comment: I am using doEvent to keep updating UI thread. There is a little idle time to check the button clicking event. I just want to know how to finish running application on the UI thread without closing form

Answer (score 2):

Please read [BackgroundWorker Class Sample for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

Designing applications that block the UI thread and then hope to be able to react to events during potential idle times is asking for trouble. Your UI will never be fully responsive and it will be a nightmare for anyone else to maintain and/or debug. The UI thread is intended to do one thing, interact with the UI. Long-running tasks are meant to be run on background threads and potentially split across multiple threads and/or cores.